# React Project "yarn build" again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have finished React Project yarn build it to static and hosted on server.

But when I have to **Update** something, first I change on to my local project then **yarn build** again.Then  I delete previews files on server and put a new ones. this goes on and on. I'm planning React + Laravel Project but I don't want every time I update something to do yarn build again and again. is there any other way to update React(already built) files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) to sync files between different machines.

If you are familiar with JavaScript, there is a tool called [shipit](https://github.com/shipitjs/shipit) that you can use to build&deploy automatically in a few lines of JavaScript code.